# rearrangement of digits of powers of 2

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Which nontrivial powers can be obtained by rearrangement of digits of powers of 2 ?

---

source - own curiosity, as usual in such cases...

---

Here are 3 interesting cases I discovered:

- powers of 3 -- obviously impossible (sum of digits).
- powers of 4 -- trivial.
- powers of 5 -- possible: $2^9=512\rightsquigarrow 125=5^3$.
- powers of 6 -- obviously impossible.
- powers of 7 -- possible: $2^{10}=1024\rightsquigarrow 2401=7^4$.
- powers of 8 -- trivial.
- powers of 9 -- obviously impossible.
- powers of 10 -- obviously impossible.
- powers of 11 -- ??
- powers of 12 -- obviously impossible.
- powers of 13 -- ??
- powers of 14 -- possible: $2^{14}=16384\rightsquigarrow 38416=14^4$.
- powers of 15 -- obviously impossible.
- powers of 16 -- trivial.

Comment: A simple brute force search up until $2^{28}$ shows no cases for 11 or 13. Very intriguing, I would also like to see a solution to this problem. There were also 256 -> 625 and 2^20 -> 7^8, but no others.

Comment: thanks for your work

Comment: Wondering if Pascal's triangle, might have the answer for 11.  Sum of $n$-th row is $2^n$ but after carries it always produces $11^n$

Comment: Presumably by "rearrangement" we mean only reordering the digits? If we allow arithmetic operations -- say exponentiation -- we have $2^{24}=16777216=11^{677726}$. I did some work on the digits of powers of five (here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13829). But more needs to be done to apply anything in that paper to your current question.

Comment: Not exactly what was asked, but $2$ and $13$ have a 2nd degree connection: $2^{14}$ has the same digits as $14^4$ and $14^2$ has the same digits as $13^2$.